# DataGridView auto size columns without showing the grid

Tags: winforms, datagridview, data-binding

I need to get DataGridView column sizes without showing the the grid (for printing). I'm using data binding through DataSource (using BindingSource doesn't seem to work too).

For whatever reason I get wrong column sizes. If I show the grid in a form first, everything is fine. If I try to get column sizes after setting no DataSource and executing AutoResizeColumns(), columns are too wide (didn't autosize).

How can I force grid to do it's job without showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Use CreateControl() to initialize control, binding, handle, etc.